# What's an in between for a big red X and a big green check mark?

Tags: usability, icons, symbols, graphic-design

I'm trying to find ideas for a good, iconic, or not so iconic but still works, in between of a big red X and a green check mark.

The context is in a feedback popup to a short 3 - 5 question quiz that pops up occasionally through the lectures of an online course.

The feedback popup shows the user their score in the quiz, and suggests whether they're ready to move on and continue the lecture, may want to consider going back and reviewing, or it's flat out reccommended that they should go back an review. So basically, the user has a score that can be different values out of 100 depending on how many questions are in the quiz, and of course, how many they get correct, but there's also three divisions of score, as explained above.

- Informing a user that they've done well, and should continue the lecture, is accompanied by a large green checkmark.
- Informing a user that they haven't done well, and need to go back and review, is accompanied by a big red x.
- The middle ground, informing the user that their score is satisfactory, and can move on, but may want to consider a quick review first, is what I'm looking for. I need a symbol that represents some sort of caution, but fits in well with a green checkmark and a red x.

The red x and green checkmark I'm talking about:

[image: Red x and green check mark]

The yellow checkmark was one idea, but I'm aiming for something better. There's something about a checkmark that has me thinking in absolutes, so a satisfactory, or cautionary checkmark just doesn't seem like a perfect solution.

Another idea was a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark inside. I've used one in other parts of the course, such as when a user clicks continue without selecting a required answer, but I still don't think that's a good fit here. A cautionary triangle in user interface design seems appropriate for warning the user about technical errors, not so much as a satisfactory sign.

So what are your thoughts? Is there a good in between for a green checkmark and red x that could represent a satisfactory score on a quiz?

Comment: This is really an Icon request question, and I'm afraid these questions aren't really on topic for this site. [Please see the why this is the case here in our FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#im-having-trouble-coming-up-with-a-good-icon-for-feature-x-should-i-ask-here-for-ideas)

Comment: @JonW I understand it's a request, but isn't a discussion on a useful icon for X context extremely healthy and relevant discussion for a user experience Q&A? It wasn't a request for a specific image, or a stock icon resource, it was a question provoking discussion on a fitting icon for a given circumstance. My reputation's low on this site, and maybe I've misinterpreted the purpose of some of these tags, but I strongly disagree if you're insinuating that my question is inappropriate. Were you to untag usability, that might be understandable, but the question being closed has me baffled.

Comment: @user1803405 The phrase 'closed' is a bit of a misnomer (see [this discussion on meta](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-are-we-so-uptight?cb=1)). It really just means that the question should be rephrased a little, and while you're doing that (if you want), we shouldn't have any answers, because the answers and the question will diverge. In your case the deeper question is how represent or communicate the intermediate level(s) between correct and incorrect. This is a more interesting question, and has a greater possibility for diverse answers.

Comment: I was surprised why this was closed, so I went reading the FAQ entry refered to above. On  http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, there is a section titled "I'm having trouble coming up with a good icon for feature X. Should I ask here for ideas?" - but that does not apply here at all. It's not about an icon for a feature. I'd say it's not even about icons, it's about basic symbol language. Like 'We know the "ok" check mark, and the "error" cross. What is half way between them?' I think it's well worth reopening!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Yeah this should not have been closed.

Comment: There are a bunch of ideas used in [Wikipedia templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Done/See_also): Yellow checkmark, cut-in-half green checkmark, purple slash, yellow ≈ (for "Possilikely"), yellow or gray exclamation point, gray equal sign, yellow question mark, ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the **exclamation mark without the triangle**.

It suggests that you need to pay some more attention and is milder than a straight out red X.

Also, rather than phrasing it as, satisfactory, you can say that their current score is acceptable, but, with a bit more effort they can do much better. Rather than a warning, you are treating it as a call to action.

[image]